# Deliberately not catching Exceptions

Tags: php, exception

So I have this little bit of code

```
public function getPrices($debtorId)
{
    $priceListId = $this->getPriceListId($debtorId);
    if(!$priceListId){
        throw new \Exception('No list found for this customer');
    }

    // doing some operations here that require $priceListId

    return $prices;
```

Up until now, I would have done something like

```
if(!$priceListId) exit('No list found for this customer');
```

The difference being, that I could catch the Exception *if I want to*, while that's not possible with the exit statement.

However, in this case I do want my program to exit. But my IDE warns me that I'm not catching Exceptions. So, should I really do this now:

```
try {
    $prices = $priceHandler->getPrices($debtorId);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

The latter appears to me as unecessary and actually decreasing code quality. So: **Is it acceptable to deliberately NOT catch some exceptions?** Or should I even get rid of the exception alltogether and just use plain old `exit`?

I tried searching for this question, but I only got results about people who had technical problems with try/catch not working.

Comment: I know it is not PHP specific, but I do believe you would get a better idea of an answer to your question. Read about the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-eafp) and [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-lbyl) python coding styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should not catch your exception there if you do not want to.

Even if you want to catch it, it could very easily be somewhere else, so you definitely do not have to wrap this in a try-catch.

Instead, you should tell your IDE that this method is supposed to throw an exception:

```
/**
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function getPrices($debtorId)
```

Comment: Ah, seems like exactly the (two bits of) info I needed. I'll wait a moment to see if someone has something more to say before accepting the answer

Comment: My experience (with PHPStorm at least) is that this might get rid of a notification _within_ the function, but will still warn you when you're _using_ the function that the thrown exception is not being caught.  The try/catch block that OP shows in the question _would_ be needed to get rid of that warning.

Comment: @WilliamRandokun Note that IDE's like PHPStorm will give you the option to add the option to add the `@throw` tag if you are on that line and press alt-enter (on a mac).

Comment: @PatrickQ Then where you are using that function, you should add the `@throws` tag as well.  This conveniently shows you what the method can return / throw even if it is thrown somewhere else. And PHPStorm will generate all that automatically when you do `/**` followed by `enter` before your method.

Comment: @jeroen Right, but that just pushes the warning further up the call chain.  OP is talking about not catching the exception anywhere.  I'm not really disagreeing with your answer, I'm just not sure if it completely removes the warnings for cases where you're knowingly never catching a thrown exception.

Comment: @PatrickQ you are right, the higher level code where I call getPrices() is still outlined with the warning. Then again it makes sense because that higher level code WILL eventually throw an Exception.

Comment: @PatrickQ True, it pushes the warning further up and to remove it there, you would have to do the same. It would remove the warning completely if you do it everywhere from where the method is called, even if you never catch the exception in the end.